# Error deploy heroku nodejs app

Tags: node.js, heroku

When i deploy application, i get error - Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/access.log' at Error (native)
what is happend?
index.js:

```
var app = require('./src/app');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

enter code here

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: share your. /src/app if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yarn, one of the most recent versions (1.0.0rc?) is causing this problem. If you set the yarn version explicity in your package.json engines config to an earlier version, like 0.27.5, that should solve your problem. i.e:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8.2.1",
  "yarn": "0.27.5"
},
```

At least this fixed the issue for me.